# Hide a part of WebView in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-web, react-native-webview

I would like to know if it is possible to hide some part of a webView. For example, I'm using youtube and I would like to hide the search bar on top of the webView. Is this possible ?

I tried with putting a view with a height but it's not working..

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You can try to inject js with `injectedJavaScript` prop and set style to `display=none`. Check [this](https://www.undefinednull.com/2015/12/27/injecting-custom-javascript-into-react-natives-webview/)

Comment: So if I want to hide the search bar, I will do : `document.querySelector('#header-bar').style.display = none` ? And then inject this in injectedJavascript ?

Comment: How can I access to the youtube html code ?

Comment: Open the url of your webview in browser and inspect the html to get the selector.

Comment: Yeah `#header-bar` is the selector, but when I try it doesn't work

Comment: document.querySelector('#header-bar').style.display = 'none'.
'none' should be in commas